# How to get name of the kendo window in the close event

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I create several instance of a generic window and all of them have an event handler for their close event. How can I get their `ID` or `Name` in this event?

Something like:

```
var name = this.wrapper.name();
```

Comment: This will work:

function onClose(e) {
   $(this.element).attr('id');
}

Comment: Yeah, your suggestion works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get window element ID with this code

```
function onClose(e) {
   var sender = e.sender,
       id = sender.element[0].id;
}
```